# Mysql i can't save data types on table settings

Tags: mysql-workbench

Hello i can't save my data types on table settings, However when i try to apply changes it seems as saved on the table information section which is on the bottom left. But on the settings it is not visible. I'm adding a photo to describe it better. I'm using course schemas and all settings are on default. I think because of this i'm getting error on foreign keys. I can't use them at all (I can't check the box on foreign keys) because data types are not matching.

I'm using windows 11 fully updated.

All of my drivers are updated.

I'm using high-end pc so specs are more than enough.

I formatted my pc twice and reinstalled Mysql workbench and server multiple times(I also tried different versions such as (8.0.32-8.0.31.-8.0.20-8.0.16-8.0.12-8.0.11)) but i couldn't find a solution on anywhere. Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6COD.png)

As you see on the photo for candy_product_id BIGINT and perms are missing , for cogs and price DECIMAL and their perms are missing. However on the bottom left as you see i actually saved them. After i click on apply and save the changes these datas are dissappering.

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: As I mentioned on my post I also tried latest version. The result is same.